# Updating navigational properties sets them to null in EF Core

Tags: c#, reflection, entity-framework-core, automapper, navigation-properties

I have a situation when I'm attempting to update navigational properties in Entity Framework Core and I'm getting some unusual behaviour where it sets the value to null which then removes the record from the database.

Simplified example:

```
public class Hla : BaseEntity
{
    public string AField1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; }
    public int PatientId { get; set; }
}

public class Patient : BaseEntity
{
    public string Test { get; set; }
    public virtual Hla Hla { get; set; }
}

public class PatientRepository : Repository, IPatientRepository
{
    private readonly SearchAndMatchContext _context;

    public PatientRepository(SearchAndMatchContext context) : base(context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<Patient> RetrieveEntity(int id)
    {
        return await _context.Patients
            .Include(t=>t.Hla)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Id == id);
    }

    public  void UpdateEntity(Patient entity)
    {
        _context.Patients.Update(entity);
    }
}
```

The code that's causing the issue:

```
private static Hla Map(Hla original, Hla update)
{
    var  fieldsToSkip = new string[]{"Id"};
    
    PropertyInfo[] fields = update.GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach (var field in fields)
    {
        if (fieldsToSkip.Contains(field.Name))
        {
            continue;
        }

        var newValue = field.GetValue(update);
        field.SetValue(original, newValue);
    }

    return original;
}

var patient = await _patientRepository.RetrieveEntity(1);

Map(patient.Hla, new Hla
    {
        AField1 = "dfgdfg",
        PatientId = patient.Id
    });

patientRepository.UpdateEntity(patient);
await _patientRepository.UnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
```

As soon as the `SaveChangesAsync` is called, the `Hla` is being set to null - output from the immediate window:

[image]

Whereas, if I have a simple "direct" mapper, it seems to work perfectly.

More simple mapper:

```
private static void Map(Hla current, Hla update)
{
    current.AField1 = update.AField1;
}
```

Then I get the immediate window output as:

[image]

I'm a little bit confused about why this happens, it seems to make no sense to me.

This also happens if I use an automapper etc.

What am I missing?

Comment: That `UpdateEntity` does nothing, unless change tracking is disabled in the DbContext configuration. EF is already tracking the instance, it already knows what was updated and will persist all detected changes whether `Update` is called or not

Comment: What's the point of `Map` ??? The code is trying to update an entity, not map anything. The field names are hard-coded, so why not just write `patient.Hla.Field1="whatever";` and call `SaveChangesAsync` right away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `Map(Hla original, Hla update)` copy all properties (except `Hla.Id`), this include the properties `Hla.Patient` and `Hla.PatientId`. But the copy from `Hla update` hasn't patient :

```cs
var patient = await _patientRepository.RetrieveEntity(1);

Map(patient.Hla, new Hla
    {
        AField1 = "dfgdfg",
        PatientId = patient.Id
        //No patient set
    });
```

Then `Map` set in the orignal `Patient <- null`.
Next EF detect the modification, update in DB and apply in all entities include the `Patient`.

The solution is to exclude from the copy the properties `Patient` and `PatientId`:

```cs
private static Hla Map(Hla original, Hla update)
{
    var  fieldsToSkip = new string[]{"Id", "PatientId", "Patient"};

    PropertyInfo[] fields = update.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (var field in fields)
    {
        if (fieldsToSkip.Contains(field.Name))
        {
            continue;
        }
        var newValue = field.GetValue(update);
        field.SetValue(original, newValue);
    }
    return original;
}
```

EDIT : Other solution is to set the property `Patient` in copy from instance :

```cs
Map(patient.Hla, new Hla
    {
        AField1 = "dfgdfg",
        PatientId = patient.Id,
        Patient = patient
    });
```

Comment: A better solution would be to just delete `Map`. The code is simply trying to update a *single* field, not map any results

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos
Bear in mind that this is a minimal example. I don't find it useful to provide a lot of unnecessary code when I can prove my problem with a minimal example.

Comment: @scottdavidwalker Does that answer your question?

Comment: @vernou - Yes, upvoted and accepted as answer. Can't believe I missed it !!!

Answer (score -1):

`Map` doesn't seem very useful here. It's not used to map, it's used to set a single property in an entity. The fields are hard-coded so nothing is gained by this. The question's code could be replaced with just :

```
var patient = await _patientRepository.RetrieveEntity(1);
patient.AField1 = "dfgdfg";
await _patientRepository.UnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
```

The call to `Update` isn't useful either because EF already tracks the `patient` entity and will detect any changes. `Update` is only needed with untracked/detached objects, to tell EF to start tracking the object in the `Updated` state.

Comment: Downvoted as you haven't explained why the null was happening. It's more iterating the point that you've already made in multiple comments.

Comment: @scottdavidwalker in that case the question itself should be downvoted for using such unnecessary code in the first place and *causing* the bug. Which, by the way, is the only problem demonstrated by this code (apart from the possible antipattern). That's not how Stack Overflow works though.